# How to avoid implicit int coercion to string in JavaScript without sprintf?

Tags: javascript, string, printf, coercion

Today I've had to take a break from debugging my code to debug my debug messages. Consider:

```
let x = 1;
console.log('x is ' + x + ' and x-1 is ' + x-1);
//                                         ^^^
// 'NaN'
```

I get why this happens: by the time we get to the subtraction, x is already a string, and it makes no sense to subtract an integer from a string. (But if x gets multiplied by 2 instead, the result is the intuitively correct `2`; and when you add an 1 to x, you get `11`, also understood).

The question is, is there a way to avoid or work around this behavior, since [there is no `sprintf()` equivalent in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format)? In my case x was a loop index and an array index and it took me a moment to catch why my console.log statements were showing nonsense.

Comment: Surround `x-1` in parentheses. Your issue is operator precedence.

Comment: Why, of course it is! Would you post it as a reply? Thanks!

Comment: don't concat the strings: `console.log('x is', x,'and x-1 is', x-1)` or [Using_string_substitutions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console#Using_string_substitutions) `console.log('x is %o and x-1 is %o', x, x-1);`